# Install problem with ros2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I attempt to install the prerequisites (OSRF sources for DDS) on the ros2 install I find a key problem. For example, when I type:

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys D2486D2DD83DB69272AFE98867170598AF249743

it times  out with the msg:

gpg: requesting key AF249743 from hkp server ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error

Reading the net some have said to add port 80 to the command, but when I use:

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80  --recv-keys D2486D2DD83DB69272AFE98867170598AF249743

it does not recognize that host and gives me:
gpgkeys: no keyserver host provided
gpg: keyserver internal error
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error

I had no problem installing the original ros.  Any advice appreciated.

Regards,
Nolan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220787/install-problem-with-ros2/) by [Nolan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25058/nolan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually I fixed this myself. You go to the MIT PGP Key Server (http://pgp.mit.edu/) - input the text string into the search and do the search. You will probably have to put 0x in front of your string. You then copy the key and paste it into a text file, which you can import on the command line via    gpg --import key.txt

I did have a problem farther downstream however. When I tried to run the talker and listener it could not find a library. The error msg was:

error while loading shared libraries: libddskernel.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I assume I need to get DDS now, so any advice on that?

Regards,
Nolan

---

Originally posted by [Nolan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25058/nolan/) with karma: 16 on 2015-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-12**:
Nolan, ROS2 is currently in alpha and rather experimental. I suggest you report issues you encounter while testing/developing at [ros2/ros2/issues](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues).

As to your problem: that is not really ROS2 specific, but seems more like a network issue, local to your infra.

**Comment by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) on 2017-01-17**:
Were you able to figure this out?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-18**:
@Sidd: things have changed so much since November last year that it could very well be that you have a different problem.

In any case, I would still advice you to post an issue over at [ros2/ros2/issues](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues).

**Comment by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) on 2017-01-19**:
Thanks, I think I missed out on a dependency before installing ros2.0. Carefully went through all the steps again, and can confirm that the installation page for ros2 (https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Linux-Development-Setup) works perfectly.